# Async rails action with responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous

Basically, what i need is:

When user press button "Parse" it sends request to the server (using ajax) and execute controller action with loop. It must be done asynchronous and user must get response how many percentage is finished (like loader...)

What is the best method of implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

The most difficult task with what you're describing is updating the loader to show the right percentage. If you can do without, I suggest you do. If you really want a loader because the parsing takes a lot of time, I can see 3 options:

- Use websockets to send the percentage to the user once it is updated. Rails will be including Actioncable in Rails 5 to easily do this but you can try it out now: https://github.com/rails/actioncable
- Use a third party service such as https://pusher.com/ to easily implement this without managing your own websocket server
- Or save the percentage in Redis and create an endpoint that you'll ping every second or so to update the loader. It feels a bit hacked but sometimes it's enough.

Good luck!